# What is wrong with this tab JS?

Tags: javascript, jquery, css

I am using a tab script from here http://www.sunsean.com/idTabs/#advanced.  It is under the "Usual" tab.  The jsfiddle below also calls jquery.idTabs.min.js.  You will see it under "External Resources".  Can anyone see what I am doing wrong - why the tabs aren't rendering?

http://jsfiddle.net/PM3zG/

```
 <div id="usual1" class="usual"> 
  <ul> 
    <li><a href="#tab1" class="selected">Tab 1</a></li> 
    <li><a href="#tab2">Tab 2</a></li> 
    <li><a href="#tab3">Tab 3</a></li> 
  </ul> 
  <div id="tab1" style="display: block; ">This is tab 1.</div> 
  <div id="tab2" style="display: none; ">More content in tab 2.</div> 
  <div id="tab3" style="display: none; ">Tab 3 is always last!</div> 
</div>
```

Comment: Well you didn't include jQuery... http://jsfiddle.net/ExplosionPIlls/PM3zG/1/

Comment: When I try your examples, it still doesn't show any tabs.

Comment: Why not use jQuery UI tabs?

Comment: Timestamp: 4/8/2013 3:59:09 PM
Error: TypeError: $(...).idTabs is not a function
Source File: http://fiddle.jshell.net/PM3zG/show/
Line: 26

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You didn't include jQuery; idTabs requires it to run.

`<script src="jquery.min.js"></script>`

http://jsfiddle.net/PM3zG/4/

To show 'tabs', you'll need CSS styling: http://jsfiddle.net/PM3zG/5/

Comment: Guess I should have used a different tab example.  Do you know of one like this but with tab styling.

Comment: I would make my own styling. It's not too difficult; I've made a simple outline (update answer).

Also consider using Bootstrap (http://twitter.github.io/bootstrap/javascript.html#tabs) if you don't want to do too much styling.

Answer (score 1):

You need to warp $("#usual1 ul").idTabs();  inside document ready event try :

```
$(document).ready(function(){
    $("#usual1 ul").idTabs(); 
});
```

Answer (score 1):

There is no mistake in your code you just need to add correct resource.
please add latest jquery.min.js and css for tabs.

Here is the jsfiddle

```
`http://jsfiddle.net/PM3zG/7/`
```

Answer (score 0):

## [*jsFiddle Demo*](http://jsfiddle.net/PM3zG/6/)

You need to have `css styles` for your tab's.

I just included this css http://www.sunsean.com/idTabs/main.css in your fiddle and now that seem's to work as required.

And as other's have already pointed out - jquery was not included in your fiddle.